# Ignite throws exception after upgrading from 1.7 to 2.3

Tags: java, spring, ignite

Exception is: **Ignite Discovery SPI implementation does not support node ordering and cannot be used with cache (use SPI with DiscoverySpiOrderSupport annotation, like TcpDiscoverySpi)**

```
<bean id="igniteConfig" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <util:list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="rateLimitterBuckets" />
                <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED" />
                <property name="rebalanceMode" value="SYNC" />
                <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                    <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder.SingletonFactory">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.TouchedExpiryPolicy">
                                <constructor-arg>
                                    <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                                        <constructor-arg value="DAYS" />
                                        <constructor-arg value="1" />
                                    </bean>
                                </constructor-arg>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="eagerTtl" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </util:list>
    </property>

    <property name="gridLogger">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4JLogger" />
    </property>

    <property name="includeEventTypes">
        <list>
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CLIENT_NODE_DISCONNECTED" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CLIENT_NODE_RECONNECTED" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="metricsLogFrequency" value="3600000" />

    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I do use `TcpDiscoverySpi`. I checked sources it's marked with `@DiscoverySpiOrderSupport(true)` annotation.

But still exception is there. Hence the question: how to fix that?

**UPD 1**: Adding a stack trace (I stripped part that is irrelevant -- I have couple beans dependent on Ignite, so they cant be created because of this exception)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [farm-connection-ignite.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Discovery SPI implementation does not support node ordering and cannot be used with cache (use SPI with @DiscoverySpiOrderSupport annotation, like TcpDiscoverySpi)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Discovery SPI implementation does not support node ordering and cannot be used with cache (use SPI with @DiscoverySpiOrderSupport annotation, like TcpDiscoverySpi)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.initializeDefaultCacheConfiguration(IgnitionEx.java:2234)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.initializeConfiguration(IgnitionEx.java:2179)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1678)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1652)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1080)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:578)
    at org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpring.start(IgniteSpring.java:66)
    at org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpringBean.afterPropertiesSet(IgniteSpringBean.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 92 more
```

Comment: Looks like `TcpDiscoverySpi` or `DiscoverySpiOrderSupport` class is loaded from an incorrect version of Ignite. Make sure, that your app doesn't suffer from a jar hell of any kind.

Comment: Also please provide full stack trace of the exception

Comment: @Denis, thank you. I updated question with a stack trace. Also I checked on "jar hell" and the only version of Ignite that I can see in maven's dependency hierarchy and the one is added to war/WEB-INF/lib is 2.3.0. I don't see other versions there. Except `ignite-shmem-1.0.0`, but i don't think it has something to do with it.

Comment: Check, what's in your classpath at runtime. You can do it by printing result of System.getProperty("java.class.path") or by following this post: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/
My best guess is that you have multiple jars of Ignite on the classpath, or some uber-jar, that contains Ignite inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears It's not a jar hell, I've checked the classpath.

It's a Spring Context AOP hell, when Spring wraps beans with Proxies. Proxy has zero annotations. Hence IgniteUtils.discoOrdered don't see those. 
In my application context xml config I have

```
<bean id="facadeMonitoringAdvisor" class="net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringAdvisor">
    <property name="pointcut">
        <bean class="org.springframework.aop.support.JdkRegexpMethodPointcut">
            <property name="pattern" value=".*Impl.*" />
            <property name="excludedPattern" value=".*PerfSens.*" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now interesting questions are:

- why it worked in 1.7.0. There must have been some code that was able to work with proxies.
- why it's even affecting TcpDiscoverySpi bean, pattern clearly shouldn't match `TcpDiscoverySpi`

I'll update this answer if I find out more.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem by applying configuration, that you provided in the question. Please provide all details, that lead to the failure, or publish your project on GitHub. Otherwise people won't be able to help you.